# git submodule for zxing (iPhone version)?

Tags: iphone, git, zxing

I need a qrcode library for an iphone project. Zxing seems the obvious choice and I've used it previously. However, this will be a project that I will have to support for quite a while and  I'm very deep in git.

Zxing officially only provides an svn repo, and gitorious has a few old zxing submodules but those that I've found are for android and even they don't get touched anymore.

I did some looking and there doesn't seem to be a git submodule for iphone. Does anyone know of a good one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/joelind/zxing-iphone - seems to be the latest one on the github.

However, you can make the git repo on your own - just by mirroring google svn.

Comment: No idea how I didn't find this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I maintain

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

It's a git-svn clone and is updated automatically within a few minutes of any svn commit. It's not officially official but I am a zxing committer.

It's not just the iphone directory, though. That's too complicated to maintain separately. The iphone directory requires the cpp (C++) directory and the C++ code is tested against the java tests in the core directory. There's also a generic objc directory for lower level code that works on both OS X and iOS.

Comment: This is also a very good resource. I wish I could mark you both correct.